# How to fix Wordpress Dropdown Menu of All Terms in Custom Taxonomy that don't show list?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to fix a problem found in this project: http://farmaciassaopaulo-com.umbler.net/.

Below the banner are the 'categories' and 'tags' buttons that should list the custom wordpress categories.

But the drop down menu does not display the listing.

Using the browser console we can see the listing,
but for some coding failure I couldn't figure out where the error comes from.

Could any Wordpress expert guide me?

Best regards.

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">CATEGORIAS
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 100%;">                                     
    <?php                                           
        $args = array('parent' => 0);
        $terms = get_terms('categorias', $args);
        foreach( $terms as $term ):
        $children = get_terms( 'categorias', array('parent' => $term->term_id));
    ?>

        <li class="lista-categoria font-museo-sans-300 dropdown-submenu">

            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $term->term_id ) ?>">
                <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                <?php if ($children) { ?>
                <span class="caret-right"></span>
                <?php } ?>
            </a>

            <?php if ($children) { ?>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <?php foreach( $children as $childrens ): ?>

            <li>
                <a tabindex="-1" href="<?php echo get_category_link( $childrens->term_id ) ?>">
                    <?php echo $childrens->name;?>
                </a>
            </li>                                                   

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

            <?php } ?>                                              

        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: The link shared does not open.